# Install Windows XP over elementary?

Tags: system

It's a good os however runs slower than windows 10 on my low-end computer. How do I change the os back to Windows? I have a USB stick and it isn't being read on elementary (it is working properly on my laptop)thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do a change back/rollback to Windows XP, or any previous Operating System that you had before the install.

If you have a Windows (XP, or any other version of Windows) installation disk, then you could use it to install Windows on your computer. As far as drivers go, I wish you good luck.

A better option, is that you have a backup of your previous system. (This includes the entire disk.) Then you could restore the previous system from the back up.

Wish you good luck.

Comment: When I see "XP" in a post involving Windows it rears a number of concerns. Chiefly among those is the security vulnerabilities that are opened up by using an OS that went end of life almost four years ago. That, along with the financial implication of buying a newer Windows version (which could cause the same issue on a lower spec machine) would cause me to look at a "lighter" Linux distro. An unprotected, outdated OS could spell certain disaster in the end.